# specified cast is not valid on linq

Tags: c#, linq-to-dataset

I am importing excel file to a DataGridView and I have to get the average of some column. It all works fine when I try it on a sample excel file which is about 300 rows. But when I try it with the actual excel file with 41000 rows, I get the error "specified cast is not valid" when I click the button to compute the average. I really don't know whats wrong and don't know how to solve it. Here's the code I use to get the average, the error is on the columns I group by.

```
private void Ave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindingSource bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();
    bindingSource1.DataSource = (from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                 group r by new
                                 {
                                     RNCID = r.Field<Double?>("RNCID"),
                                     Date = r.Field<DateTime>("Date"),
                                     WBTSNAME = r.Field<String>("WBTSNAME")

                                 } into g

                                 select new
                                 {
                                     g.Key.Date,
                                     g.Key.RNCID,
                                     g.Key.WBTSNAME,
                                     VSLCDLMeanLicenseGroupShare = g.Average(r => r.Field<Double>("VS LC DLMean LicenseGroup Share")),
                                     VSLCDLCreditAvailableShared = g.Average(r => r.Field<Double>("VS LC DLCreditAvailable Shared")),
                                     VSLCULMeanLicenseGroupShare = g.Average(r => r.Field<Double>("VS LC ULMean LicenseGroup Share")),
                                     VSLCULCreditAvailableShared = g.Average(r => r.Field<Double>("VS LC ULCreditAvailable Shared")),
                                     UtilDL = g.Average(r => r.Field<Double?>("Util DL")),
                                     UtilUL = g.Average(r => r.Field<Double?>("Util UL")),

                                 });

    dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
}
```

here's the stack trace I got

```
System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
```

Message="Specified cast is not valid."
  Source="System.Data.DataSetExtensions"
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.DataRowExtensions.UnboxT`1.NullableField[TElem](Object value)
       at System.Data.DataRowExtensions.Field[T](DataRow row, String columnName)
       at CE_Fin.Form1.<Ave_Click>b__0(DataRow r) in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Final\CE_Fin\Form1.cs:line 215
       at System.Linq.Lookup`2.Create[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
       at System.Linq.GroupedEnumerable`3.GetEnumerator()
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
       at System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.GetListFromEnumerable(IEnumerable enumerable)
       at System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.ResetList()
       at System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.set_DataSource(Object value)
       at CE_Fin.Form1.Ave_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Final\CE_Fin\Form1.cs:line 214
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at CE_Fin.Program.Main() in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Final\CE_Fin\Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:

Comment: Please show the exact exception. It's likely that it's one of those `Field` calls which is failing, but we can't tell which without any more information.

Answer (score 0):

The likely cause is that one of these fields has a null value:

```
r.Field<Double>("VS LC DLMean LicenseGroup Share")
r.Field<Double>("VS LC DLCreditAvailable Shared")
r.Field<Double>("VS LC ULMean LicenseGroup Share")
r.Field<Double>("VS LC ULCreditAvailable Shared")
```

Make them nullable `<double?>` (as you already do for `"Util DL"` and `"Util UL"`)

Comment: @helix - then please show the exception stack trace